# define Vs static constant Vs NSString -- Memory point of view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, constants

What is the best bet between:

```
#define kYes @"Yes"
```

AND

```
static NSString *const kYes = @"Yes";
```

And

```
NSString *kYes = @"Yes";
```

from memory consumption point of view. Keeping in mind that there will be thousands of constants in the application.

Comment: You mean `#define kYes @"Yes"`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the memory stand point - static variable is better, since it's referenced once.
The #define will insert the string into all the occurrences, by that - multiplying the memory usage... (that is unless GCC optimizing same constant string occurrences, which it actually might. in that case - there is no difference)

Comment: *unless GCC optimizing same constant string occurrences* — which is the case.

Comment: Does it mean if a #define  is used at 10 places, it would  replace the String and eventually create more objects. ex: if ([a isEqualToString:KYes]){}... which will be if ([a isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){} , 1 object. another place we intialize to NSString *status = KYes , which will be .. NSString *status = @"Yes" , 2nd object